# Aggregation and joining 2 tables or Sub Queries

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, subquery, aggregate-functions

I have the following tables.

Order_table

| Order_ID | Item_ID | Qty_shipped |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1111 | 11 | 4 |
| 1111 | 22 | 6 |
| 1111 | 33 | 6 |
| 1111 | 44 | 6 |

Shipping_det

| Order_ID | Ship_num | Ship_cost |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1111 | 1 | 16.84 |
| 1111 | 2 | 16.60 |
| 1111 | 3 | 16.60 |

I want my output to be as follows,

| Order ID | Qty_shipped | Ship_cost |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1111 | 22 | 50.04 |

I wrote the following query,

```
select sum(O.qty_shipped) as Qty_shipped, sum(S.Ship_cost) as Total_cost
from Order_table O
join shipping_det S on O.Order_ID = S.Order_ID
```

and I got my output as

| Qty_shipped | Total_cost |
| --- | --- |
| 66 | 200.16 |

As per my understanding, because I joined the two tables, Qty_shipped got multipled 3 times and Total_cost got multiplied 4 times.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to aggregate before joining.  Or, to union the table together and then aggregate:

```
select order_id, sum(qty_shipped), sum(ship_cost)
from ((select order_id, qty_shipped, 0 as ship_cost
       from order_table
      ) union all
      (select order_id, 0, ship_cost
       from shipping_det
      )
     ) os
group by order_id;
```